# Flawed Cantor Set cardinality calculation

Tags: cantor-set

Years ago a professor explained that the Cantor Set is uncountable the following way:

C0 has two endpoints, C1 has four endpoints, C2 has eight endpoints, etc.

Therefor Cn has 2^n endpoints and thus the set of all endpoints is 2^**N**. Now, since 2^**N** is uncountable, and the endpoints is a subset of the full Cantor set, therefor the Cantor Set is uncountable.

At first glance this made sense to me but then I realized that the endpoints are all Rational!

Obviously this "proof" is flawed but my question is, where is the flaw?

Comment: "... and thus the set of all endpoints is $2^\mathbb N$" is totally bogus.

Comment: Well, the flaw is clearly either that the set of all endpoints is 2^N or that 2^N is uncountable.  I know the latter is widely recognized as true so the former must be where the flaw lies.  I suppose my real question is why?  What is wrong with the way he came with 2^N?

Comment: $\mathbf{2}^\mathbb{N}$ is not a set of points on the real line but the family of all sets of natural numbers.

Comment: He didn't say how he came up with $2^N$, except "thus".  Be very wary of "thus"...